# what design pattern can be used for changes?

Tags: design-patterns, uml

I'm working on modeling an application for wireless service. For every year they change the plan offers. So what design pattern can be used in class diagram so that it can be changed every 1 year?

Comment: What is your current design? Why do you think you need a design pattern?

Comment: Whats changing exactly? How they calculate something? Provide more information.

Comment: My doubt is do we have to use design pattern for something that changes frequently? or we can design it normal

Comment: What comprises a "plan offer"? Which parts of it change every year? Which parts remain constant?

Comment: like data plans and minutes they will be offered or rates etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the details, but there are some patterns that come to mind here. If aspects of the plan require a variety of algorithms to be used, you could consider Strategy. If there's a high-level algorithm that applies to the general plan where the details vary for different types of plan, Template Method might be useful.

However you need to study the problem carefully and see if patterns will really help you. The tone of your question suggests you might be "pattern happy" -- looking for places to apply a pattern rather than being driven by the needs of your design.

Comment: can strategy pattern can be applied to where customer have to select different parts from different models to build their custom pc?

Comment: +1 "Pattern happy" makes the overall design unhappy....

Comment: No, that doesn't sound like a place to apply Strategy.

Comment: What can be used for selecting different parts for custom pc and calculate their cost?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any design pattern as such to model this situation.

The challenge is to determine what is common for all plans - the "core plan" if you will. All other aspects should either be part of a subclass such as PlanActivePerJune7th2012 or stored as some kind of attributes or key/value pairs. The advantage of the first approach is that you will have type-safe methods and attributes. The advantage of the other is flexibility.